# How do I properly uninstall/fix python 3.8.5 when the installer doesn't work?

Tags: python, windows, pip, uninstallation

After messing up my pip installation (I interrupted an update), I tried reinstalling python, but it didn't fix pip. After trying to uninstall python and re-install it manually, the installer just simply won't work for 3.8.5. After removing all python directories (to my knowledge), it still shows up in control panel, and the installer sees it, but can't uninstall it. All it says is "uninstall successful".
*Older versions would not install as they detect an existing installation.*

The files I've removed:

> %programfiles%\python
> %appdata%\python
> %userprofile%\local\programs\python
> %userprofile%\local\programs\pip

I have also removed python from path, and the registry entry.

*For any more information, feel free to comment.*

***Thanks in advance***

Comment: I know it might not work, but can you type `where python` in CMD and copy-paste the reply? Just be sure to omit any personal info.

Comment: Python is no longer in my path, so... it didn't work. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to remove the registry key from

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

with information from [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/247501/how-to-manually-remove-programs-from-the-add-remove-programs-list). Then I brought up the uninstaller prompt again, which still showed the "Modify, Repair & Uninstall" options from earlier, but I right-clicked the icon on the taskbar (When a program is open) and clicked on properties, finding the path to that executable:

`%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{de694e50-e0d0-48a5-9a7a-56fd037154e2}`

I deleted that file, and then when I clicked "uninstall" in control panel again, it said if I'd like to remove it from the program list as it couldn't find it.

After that, the installer now can't see Python installed.